# Maintaining property order with get-member

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a query that grabs all the columns from a table then I do some work on it.  The problem is I work with the column names for an insert but they are in a different order because of Get-Member.  Is there a way to get the property names (column names) and maintain order or re-order the System.Data.DataRow.  I must maintain property types.

**Commands:**
$dataColumns = $dataGatherOut | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$dataColumns

**Results:**
PS C:\Windows\system32> $dataColumns

alpha

check

loan

---

**Commands:**
$dataGatherOut

**Results:**

check                   : 1234

loan                : Test Values

alpha                   : 4568

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$dataGatherOut.psobject.properties | select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Anyway to exclude RowError, RowState, Table, HasErrors and ItemArray?  I did the following and it works I doubt it would match any columns in my DB but so many tables unsure.  $dataGatherOut.psobject.properties | select -ExpandProperty Name | Where-Object{(-not($_ -match 'RowError|RowState|Table|HasErrors|ItemArray'))}

Comment: You can add the ^$ anchors to insure you don't match anything else, and you don't really need the where-object,  ($dataGatherOut.psobject.properties | select -ExpandProperty Name) -notmatch '^(RowError|RowState|Table|HasErrors|ItemArray)$'

Comment: so this was working but now I'm getting PS C:\Windows\system32> $dataGatherOut.psobject.properties | select -ExpandProperty Name
Count
Length
LongLength
Rank
SyncRoot
IsReadOnly
IsFixedSize
IsSynchronized    
Not sure why the behavior changed

Comment: Hard to say.  Open an new question and post the code.  We'll get it sorted out........